# Spring Cloud Streams Conditional Forwarding of Data to Kafka Topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to send Data to different topics based on some evaluation. I am using SPring CLoud Streams and Kafka

How can I conditionally forward to kafka topics. I need to insert SCS-kafka related code in the places where I commented specifically.

Thank you.

```
    @EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class SampleSink {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Sink.INPUT)
    public void processor(Message<?> message1) {


        EvaluateData evaluateData = someService.evaluateData(message1);

        String Result = String.valueOf(evaluateData.getResult());

        try {

            if(validationResult.equalsIgnoreCase("allgood")){

                //Send message1 to Topic1


            }

            else if (validationResult.equalsIgnoreCase("notgood")){
 new SomeException("topic1");
```

//sent data to topic2

```
            }

            else {
                throw new SomeException("topic3");
            }

        }
        catch (SomeException e){

          //something
```

//sent data to topic2 and 3 respectively
            }

```
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is essentially a router which we already provide as an out of the box application. It is basically a router Sink which will route message based on conditions you specify via configuration.
Please see more [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/router)

Comment: Hi Oleg. Thank you for the info. Could you please point me to an example or some  code snippets as to how I can use this in my above scenario ? Also, I am not using this as part of SCDF. Just trying to build a microservice which requires conditional forwarding. Thanks.

Comment: It does not require SCDF. It's a standalone spring-cloud-stream microservice which could be used in isolation. The examples are provided in the [README](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/router/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-router/README.adoc)

Comment: Can you point me to a specific example as to how I can use this in my app ? the readme doc just gives the options. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what example you are asking me to provide. The code I pointed out does exactly what you are trying to do in the above code. It is effectively an example you're looking for. Feel free to copy it or (as I suggested) use the app itself (as if it was your own). The README simply provides additional details.

Comment: Yes I get that. But I am asking you how can I simply send "message1" to a topic using either @SendTo or somehow....even if I use router which I have never used it, I am requesting help on what values I have to give for me route my message1 to a particular topic. If you could please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: I could use a processor instead of a sink but my app has conditional routing so im a bit stuck at sending to different topics. How do I do that in a plain SCS either Processor or Sink class is all what I ask.

Comment: @KennyWeeler - Did you ever get this to work? We are working on a similar scenario where we are wanting to perform conditional dispatching using ` @StreamListener(..condition=..) ` and route the message to a different Kafka topic.